# Realizar Bien Relaciones CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, code-first

Retome un proyecto donde se tiene una tabla productoIntelectual el cual tiene relación con GruposInvestigación y AreaConocimiento; en la primera tiene la relación a las mencionadas tablas de esta forma:

```
  public class ProductoIntelectual 
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string TipoProducto { get; set; }
        public int SubTipo { get; set; } //TipoArticuloCientifico
        public string NombreProducto { get; set; } //TituloArticuloCientifico
        public GruposInvestigacion gruposInvestigacion { get; set; }
        public AreaConocimiento areaConocimiento { get; set; }
    }
```

En las tablas donde se se relaciona se encuentran de esta forma:

**AreaConocimiento**

```
public class AreaConocimiento 
{
    public int id {get; set; }
    public string NombreAreaConocimiento { get; set; }
}
```

**GruposInvestigacion**

```
public class GruposInvestigacion 
    {
        public int id {get; set; }  
        public string GrupoInvestigacion { get; set; }
        public string Lider { get; set; }
        public string Correo { get; set; }
    
    }
```

al momento de realizar una consulta me sale asi...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si se ha realizado bien el codefirst? no me sale errores.

Comment: Cual es la consulta que realizas

Comment: un simple select * from ProductoIntelectual, como explique este código lo retome y no me cuadra con lo que mas o meno se de una relacion uno a muchos, en EFCore .net core 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

faltaría agregar una referencia mas para indicar que la clase Producto intelectual tendrá varias Arreas de Conocimiento y Grupos de Investigación.

Ejemplo sencillo:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public byte[]  Photo { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
        
    public Grade Grade { get; set; }
}

public class Grade
{
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Tu código quedaría algo como esto.

```
  public class ProductoIntelectual 
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string TipoProducto { get; set; }
        public int SubTipo { get; set; } //TipoArticuloCientifico
        public string NombreProducto { get; set; } //TituloArticuloCientifico
        public virtual ICollection<AreaConocimiento> areaConocimiento { get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<GrupoInvestigacion> grupoInvestigacion { get; set;}
    }

public class AreaConocimiento 
{
    public int id {get; set; }
    public string NombreAreaConocimiento { get; set; }
    public ProductoIntelectual productoIntelectual { get; set;}
}

public class GruposInvestigacion 
{
    public int id {get; set; }  
    public string GrupoInvestigacion { get; set; }
    public string Lider { get; set; }
    public string Correo { get; set; }
    public ProductoIntelectual productoIntelectual { get; set;}
}
```